# Least Squares relation with statistical formula

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, regression, least-squares

Consider a Simple Linear Regression using Least Squares. So if we have 3 equations in 2 unknows, we're fitting a line `Y = DX + C`

$$C + Dx_1 = y_1$$
$$C + Dx_2 = y_2$$
$$C + Dx_3 = y_3$$

In Linear Algebra, projection matrix for least squares is given by
$$P = A{(A^TA)}^{-1}A^TY$$
Where $[C D]^T$ is the matrix represented by 
$${(A^TA)}^{-1}A^TY$$

And in Statistics, Regression is given  by
$$ D = \frac{\sum_{i=0}^n[(X_i - \bar X)(Y_i - \bar Y)]}{\sum_{i=0}^n(X_i - \bar X)^2}$$

$$C = \bar Y - D\bar X$$

There's certainly some relation in both the equations.I want to understand how the projection formula in linear algebra evolved to give the formula in statistics.

Comment: Expand out the normal equations

Comment: It's a straight forward exercise to write out the $A$ matrix for your least squares problem and then explicitly compute $(A^{T}A)^{-1}A^{T}Y$. Thus the formula that you learned in statistics is a special case of the more general linear algebra formula for the least squares solution to a linear system of equations.

Answer (score 1):

Let us see the above relationship in even simpler case where the model is $y_i = \beta + \epsilon_i$, i.e., you have $n$ observations of the form $\{ ( y_i, 1)\}_{i=1}^n$. Namely, $n$ equations of the form $y_i=\beta$, which is clearly over-determined system as for continuous $Y$ you'll have $n$ different solutions. As such if you consider projection without any statistical considerations, you'll construct the following projection matrix
$$
H = \mathrm{1}(\mathrm{1}'\mathrm{1})^{-1}\mathrm{1}'=\frac{1}{n}J,
$$
where $J$ is a matrix with all entries equal to $1$. So, your fitted values are 
$$
Hy = \hat{y}=\frac{1}{n}(\sum_{i=1}^ny_i,..., \sum_{i=1}^ny_i)^T, 
$$
namely, your fitted values are $\hat{y}_i = \bar{y}_n $ for all $i$.

Now consider the Least square approach where you are looking for the best estimator of $\beta$ that is given by 
$$
\hat{\beta} = (X'X)^{-1}X'y=(\mathrm{1}'\mathrm{1})^{-1}\mathrm{1}'y = \bar{y}_n,
$$ 
as such every fitted value can be calculated by 
$$
\hat{y}_i = \hat{\beta}=\bar{y}_n.
$$
As you see the results are identical. To show it for you case just write down the projections matrix for 
$$
X = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & x_1 \\
1 & x_2 \\
: & : \\
1 & x_n
\end{pmatrix}
$$ 
and compare each fitted value with the OLS results. It is slightly more messy, but it follows the same logic as the aforementioned illustration.